# RegExp в JavaScript ограничение длинны

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
// Примеры строк 
var str = '/user/123';

var str2 = '/user/123/Nikita';

// Патерн для сравнивание

var pattern = /\/user\/(\w+)/;

console.log( str.search(pattern) ); // 0
console.log( str2.search(pattern) ); // 0

/* 
Мне нужно что-бы по патерну находились одинаковы с regexp строки
т.е. во втором случае (str2) должно быть -1
*/
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew str должно равняться -1 то есть  не найти совпадений

Comment: `var pattern = /^\/user\/(\w+)$/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо, помогло.